# airflow date error dag.normalize_schedule TypeError

Tags: docker, typeerror, airflow

I met a apache-airflow datetime problem as following

```
Process DagFileProcessor238215-Process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 388, in helper
    pickle_dags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1832, in process_file
    self._process_dags(dagbag, dags, ti_keys_to_schedule)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1422, in _process_dags
    dag_run = self.create_dag_run(dag)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 856, in create_dag_run
    next_run_date = dag.normalize_schedule(min(task_start_dates))
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

I use apache-airflow in docker which from [zhongjiajie/docker-airflow](https://github.com/zhongjiajie/docker-airflow) and base on [puckel/docker-airflow](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow).

and my DAG define like this

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from udf.udf_hive_operator import HiveOperator
from airflow.operators.hive_to_mysql import HiveToMySqlTransfer
from udf.udf_hive_to_oracle import HiveToOracleTransfer
from udf.utils.date_utils import gen_history_date_para, today_belong_business_day
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

TMPL_SQL_PATH = Variable.get("sql_path")
HIVE_DB = "default"
NOSTRICT_HIVE_PARTITION_MODE = "set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;\n"

default_args = {
    "owner": "xx_monitor",
    "description": "workflow for xx monitor system",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2014, 1, 1),
    "email": ["airflow@airflow.com"],
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 3,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
    # "queue": "bash_queue",
    # "pool": "backfill",
    # "priority_weight": 10,
    # "end_date": datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="drug_monitor",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="0 18 * * *",
    template_searchpath=TMPL_SQL_PATH
)
```

the `udf` module is my user define function

But the strange thing happen

- I go to `webserver UI` turn the dag `ON`, it still failed and I see error message in `schedule` as above
- I use `backfill` in cli as `airflow backfill -s 20140101 -e 20180101 <DAG_ID>`, and go to `schedule` the error message disappear and all tasks start scheduled or queued

I try several way to fix that but failed.

- try to set `start_date` in `default_args` as `airflow.utils.dates.days_ago` Object but failed, eg `days_ago(2018, 9, 5)`
- try to set `start_date` in `default_args` as `airflow.utils.timezone.datetime` Object but failed, eg `datetime(2018, 9, 5)`
- try to set `schedule_interval` in `DAG` as [DAG-runs](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html?highlight=daily#dag-runs) variable, like `@daily` but failed
- try to set `schedule_interval` in `DAG` as `datetime.timedelta` Object but failed

have everyone met problem like this, and how could I fix this?

Comment: Do any of the tasks for the process also define a start date?

Comment: @joeb  yes, fix rename task para name

Answer (score 3):

In my Dag file, I define a task with param `start_date`, I fix this to rename param.